# How to move from FragmentPagerAdapter to activity

Tags: android

I try to move from Fragment to activity specifically from

```
public class PageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private int numOfTabs;

PageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int numOfTabs) {
    super(fm);
    this.numOfTabs = numOfTabs;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return new ChatFragment();
        case 1:
        return new FragmentHome();
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return numOfTabs;
}}
```

to

```
public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home_tt); }}
```

PageAdapter  that of tablayout.

I was try to do it like that ..but not work

[image]

If anyone know solution to this problem  help me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem you have to declare the activity in the manifest and then try this:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), YourActivity.class);
            getActivity().startActivity(myIntent);
```

in the manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name=".YourActivity"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay then try this:

```
Intent readMore = new Intent(v.getContext(), YourActivity.class);
v.getContext().startActivity(readMore);
```

and post your logcat please.

Comment: still brother this is problem (Cannot resolve symbol 'v')

Comment: Try it without the v in  v.getContext().

Comment: same problem (Cannot resolve method 'getContext()')

Comment: Is Home.class a fragment?

Comment: No brother//public class Home extends AppCompatActivity as my question